# Using netlink connector in dotnet (c#)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am writing a dotnet core app and want to use the functionality provided by the linux [netlink connector](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/connector/connector.txt) to listen to process fork events.

I'm not quite sure if this can be written in dotnet since this is linux kernel code in C. Should I use pinvoke to invoke C code? How would the events be sent back to my c# handler?

Comment: I think this is probably a [so] question, rather than here (because it's programming, not because it's C#), but I don't know enough about netlink to know if there's a sysadmin element involved.

Comment: It seems to me that your question has some holes in it. Specifically: are you hoping to use an existing kernel module (to listen to process fork events), or are you planning to write your own?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. I'm not specifically familiar with what you're talking about, but I'm 75% confident that you can write your app in C#, as it would be interfacing with the kernel through a socket interface, and not direct code (function call) linkage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you cannot use dotnet to create netlink connector sockets. The underlying protocol family and address family is not supported by System.Net.Sockets, and an attempt to type cast ints to the enum doesn't work either with the socket constructor throwing a unsupported address family error.

Basically, this works

```
#include <linux/connector.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main() {
    int sock = socket(16, SOCK_DGRAM, 11);
    return 0;
}
```

But this fails

```
const UInt16 NETLINK_CONNECTOR = 11;
const UInt16 PF_NETLINK = 16;
Socket temp = new Socket((AddressFamily)PF_NETLINK, SocketType.Dgram, (ProtocolType)NETLINK_CONNECTOR);
```

throwing a

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Address
>   family not supported by protocol

Here is the github issue on the corefx repo tracking this feature - https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34015